# Plugin to quickly open a text file based on a file name in a text file

Tags: gratis, windows-7, notepad++

Consider the following text file `a.txt`, which contains references to a number of other files:

```
See also: b.txt
Then read c.txt and continue in d.txt
```

I am looking for a plugin that recognizes the file names and is able to open them in Notepad++ as well. It's ok to look for files in the same directory as the opened text file only.

I don't really care how that is done. It could be a "hyperlink", but it could also be a docked window which lists all files.

- Windows (7 x64)
- gratis